# Optimize C code

Tags: c, optimization, if-statement

I have the following code

```
    void Fun2()
    {
        if(X<=A)
            X=ceil(M*1.0/A*X);
        else
            X=M*1.0/(M-A)*(M-X);
    }
```

I want to program it in fast manner using C99, take into account the following comments.

1. `X`and `A`, are 32 bit variables and I declare them as `uint64_t`, While `M` as `static const uint64_t`.
2. This function is called by another function and the value of `A` are changed to a new value every `n` times of calling.
3. The optimization is needed in the execution time, CPU is Core i3, OS is windows 7

The math model I want to implement it is

```
F=ceil(Max/A*X) if x<=A

F=floor(M/(M-A)*(M-X)) if x>A
```

For clarity and no confusion My previous post was 
I have the following code

```
void Fun2()
{
    if(X0<=A)
        X0=ceil(Max1*X0);
    else
        X0=Max2*(Max-X0);
}
```

I want to program it in fast manner using C99, take into account the following comments.

1. X0, A, Max1, and Max2 are 32 bit variable and I declare them as uint64_t, While Max as static const uint64_t.
2. This function is called by another function and the values of Max1, A, Max2 are changed to random values every n times of calling.
3. I work in Windows 7 and in codeblocks software

Thanks

Comment: If you declare `X0` & co. as `uint64_t` but they are 32 bit variables your compiler has serious problems...

Comment: If you are using C99, don't tag C++

Comment: So what is the question? How to optimize that code? I suggest you optimize it by specifying `-O3` for the compiler... Also, if it is a library function, add an inline version to the `.h` file, so compiler has option of inlining it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not take care of C++

Comment: Also, consider asking questions regarding optimization on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The easiest obvious optimization is **not** to declare one variable as `double` when it is an integer and when all other variables are integers, too. That not only removes useless conversions and back-conversions but also makes `ceil` obsolete.

Comment: "For clarity and no confusion"... Why do you have two versions in the same question? Makes no sense. There's the edit history anyone can see, no need to put several version in the question. I'd edit the extra part out, but it's unclear and confusing enough so I'm not sure what part is the part that should be edited out...

Answer (score 3):

It is completely pointless and impossible to optimize code like this without a specific target in mind. In order to do so, you need the following knowledge:

- Which CPU is used.
- Which OS is used (if any).
- In-depth knowledge of the above, to the point where you know more, or about as much of the system as the people who wrote the optimizer for the given compiler port.
- What kind of optimization that is most important: execution speed, RAM usage or program size.

The only kind of optimization you can do without knowing the above is on the algorithm level. There are no such algorithms in the code posted.

Thus your question cannot be answered by anyone until more information is provided.

Comment: The optimization in the execution time, CPU is Core i3, OS is windows 7

Comment: @MousaFarajallah Then please edit your question and include this information.

Answer (score 0):

If "fast manner" means fast execution, your first change is to declare this function as an inline one, a feature of C99.

```
inline void Fun2()
{
   ...
   ...
}
```

I recall that GNU CC has some interesting macros that may help optimizing this code as well. I don't think this is C99 compliant but it is always interesting to note. I mean: your function has an if statement. If you can know by advance what probability has each branch of being taken, you can do things like:

```
if (likely(X0<=A)).....
```

If it's probable that X0 is less or equal than A. Or:

```
if (unlikely(X0<=A)).....
```

If it's not probable that X0 is less or equal than A.

With that information, the compiler will optimize the comparison and jump so the most probable branch will be executed with no jumps, so it will be executed faster in architectures with no branch prediction.

Another thing that may improve speed is to use the ?: ternary operator, as both branches assign a value to the same variable, something like this:

```
inline void Func2()
{
  X0 = (X0>=A)? Max1*X0 : Max2*(Max-X0);
}
```

BTW: why use `ceil()`? `ceil()` is for double numbers to round down a decimal number to the nearest non greater integer. If `X0` and `Max1` are integer numbers, there won't be decimals in the result, so `ceil()` won't have any effect.

Comment: `inline` nowadays is just used to allow exceptions to the ODR, modern compilers will inline aggressively anything when they feel so inclined; no branch is more likely (at compile time) here, since he said that `A` is changed randomly every `n` iterations; the ternary operator is exactly equivalent to those `if`s, any recent compiler will emit the same code; the `ceil` apparently is correct, he made a mess in the question with the types of the variables, it turns out `Max1` (and maybe some of the other constants) is a `double` (see comment to my answer).

Comment: -1 Because of the misleading ?: nonsense. The conditional operator does _not_ lead to faster code than `if-else`. If anything, it leads to slower code when someone who doesn't know how it works tries to use it, as in this case. The 2nd and 3rd operand will be balanced against each other, which is required by the C standard. In this example, the result will always be of type `double` no matter if the 2nd or 3rd operand of ?: is used. You have enforced a promotion of the expression `Max2*(Max-X0)` to `double`, which was not in the original code, possibly making the program slower, not faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think one thing that can be improved is not to use floating point. Your code mostly deals with integers, so you want to stick to integer arithmetic.

The only floating point number is `Max1`. If it's always whole, it can be an integer. If not, you may be able to replace it with two integers: `Max1*X0` -> `X0 * Max1_nom / Max1_denom`. If you calculate the nominator/denominator once, and use many times, this can speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd transform the math model to

```
Ceil  (M*(X-0) / (A-0))  when A<=X
Floor (M*(X-M) / (A-M))  when A>X
```

with

```
Ceil (A / B) =  Floor((A + (B-1)) / B)
```

Which substituted to the first gives:

```
((M * (X - m0) + c ) / ( A - m0))
```

where

```
c = A-1; m0 = 0, when A <= X
c = 0; m0 = M,   when A >= X
```

Everything will be performed in integer arithmetic, but it'll be quite tough to calculate the reciprocals in advance;

It may still be possible to use some form of [DDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_differential_analyzer_%28graphics_algorithm%29) to avoid calculating the division between iterations.

Using the temporary constants c, m0 is simply for unifying the pipeline for both branches as the next step is in pursuit of parallelism.